# Balanced Network max flow review

Tags: algorithms, network-flow

I would like a review for my algorithm for the following question:
A flow network is a “balanced network” if for every $v∈V- {s,t}$ it holds that $c_in (v)=c_out (v).$
Let G be a balanced network in which in-degree(s)=out-degree(t)=0
Find max-flow for G.
My Algorithm so far:

1. We will define the following capacity-function: $∀(u,v)∈E,f(ⅇ)=c(ⅇ)$
2. Run over the adj. list and update for every edge it to be our function, and return c(e)

I was also wondering how to prove its a max flow in the correctness part
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The flow defined by you, satisfies both the constraints: a) conservation of flow at each vertex -- by the definition of balanced network and b) the capacity constraint because $f_{e} = c_{e}$ for every $e \in E$. Therefore, it is a valid flow.
2. It is a max-flow because it is sending the flow of value which is equal to the *capacity* of the cut $C$ defined as: $\{s\}$ and $V \setminus \{s\}$, i.e. max-flow = $\sum_{(s,u) \in E} c(u,v)$ since there is no incoming edge to $s$. Note that any flow can not exceed the capacity of this cut. This fact follows from the *min-cut max-flow theorem*. i.e., **max-flow** $=$ **min capacity of an** $s$-$t$ **cut** $\leq$ **capacity of cut** $C$. Therefore, what we have is a max-flow.